# How to check on if statement if the elements return to true

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on my python script as I'm created a list to stored the elements in the arrays.

I have got a problem with the if statement. I'm trying to find the elements if I have the values `375` but it won't let me to get pass on the if statement.

Here is the code:

```
program_X = list()

#create the rows to count for 69 program buttons
for elem in programs_button:
    program_width.append(elem.getWidth())
    program_X.append(elem.getX())
program_X = map(str, program_X)


#get the list of position_X for all buttons
for pos_X in programs_X:

    #find the position with 375
    if pos_X == 375:
        print pos_X
```

Here is the list of elements that I use to print from the arrays:

```
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 375
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 724.06
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 1610.21
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 2496.39
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 2845.45
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 3194.51
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 3543.57
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 3892.63
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 4241.69
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 4590.75
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 4939.81
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 5288.87
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 5637.93
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 5986.99
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 6336.05
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 6685.11
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 7034.17
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 7383.23
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 7732.29
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 8081.35
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 8430.41
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 8779.47
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 9665.59
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 10014.65
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 10363.71
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 10712.77
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 11061.83
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 11410.89
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 11759.95
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 12109.01
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 12458.07
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 12807.13
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 13156.19
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 13505.25
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 13854.31
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 14203.37
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 14552.43
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 14901.49
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 15250.55
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 15599.61
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 15948.67
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 16297.73
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 17183.85
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 17532.91
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 17881.97
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 18231.03
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 18580.09
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 18929.15
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 19278.21
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 19627.27
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 19976.33
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 20325.39
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 20674.45
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 21023.51
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 21372.57
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 21721.63
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 22070.69
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 22419.75
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 22768.81
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 23117.87
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 23466.93
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 24353.05
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 24702.11
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 25051.17
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 25400.23
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 25749.29
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 26098.35
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 26447.41
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 26796.47
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 375
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 724.06
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 1610.21
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 1959.27
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 2308.33
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 3194.45
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 3543.51
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 4241.6
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 4590.66
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 4939.72
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 5825.9
14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 6174.96
```

Can you please help me how I can get pass on the if statement when I'm trying to find the elements of `375`?

Comment: Please define how you are storing the element in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the `program_x` contains string elements :

```
program_X = map(str, program_X)
                 ^
```

you need to change the following :

```
if pos_X == 375
```

to

```
if pos_X == '375'
```

Comment: thank you very much for you help. I have got a little problem, there are 7 elements in the list but it will get me to print the elements like 14 times. how I can only print the elements like 7 times not 14?

Comment: @Rob you're welcome , did you mean that `program_x` contain 7 element ?

Comment: yes of couse, the program_x will contain 14 elements which it should have 7 elements of `375`. do you want me to post full code?

Comment: it this happened after changing 375 to '375' ? can you show the elements of 'program_x' ?

Comment: it is okay, sorry I have forgot to remove the `program_X.append(elem.getX())` as I am already using `program_X.append(position_start)` that make it in multiply. so the problem are now solved. Thank you very much for your help and I wish you a very merry christmas! :)

Comment: if they are strings already why map to strings, if they are ints leave them as ints as compare to an int or at least cast when you append instead of calling map needlessly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing strings in list that way,

```
program_X = ['14:08:55 T:1260  NOTICE: 8081.35', ...]
```

Then use `in` keyword to check the word

```
for pos_X in programs_X:    
    #find the position with 375
    if '375' in pos_X:
        print pos_X
```